# Is there a Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem for the function space $C^k(\bar\Omega)$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Is there a Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem for the function space $C^k(\bar\Omega)$? More precisely, I want to prove that

THEOREM. A sequence $\{f_n\}$ is convergent in $C^k(\bar\Omega)$ (or some more general metric space $(X,d)$) if and only if every subsequence $\{f_{n_{k}}\}$ of $\{f_n\}$ has a convergent subsequence $\{f_{n_{k_{l}}}\}$  and all the subsequence $\{f_{n_{k_{l}}}\}$ have the same limit.

Any answer or reference is appreciated! :)

Comment: A space with metric has BW property means compact. Which also means complete and total bounded.

Comment: So can you find a metric to make $C^k$ complete?

Comment: @ Yimin: What's the meaning of the term "BW property"?

Comment: it means the space satisfies Bolzano-Weierstrass[BW] theorem.

Comment: @ Yimin: Can you explain your idea in details. I can't understand your comment well. Thanks! :)

Comment: @ Yimin: Actually, even though $C^k(\bar\Omega)$ doesn't have the BW property, can we prove the THEOREM I post is right?

Comment: I am not sure but I felt you still need some uniform property here for the theorem to be right.

Comment: @ Yimin: Ok, now I understand your comment,Thanks! :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7651/discussion-between-darry-and-yimin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. If $x_n\rightarrow x$, then it is obvious that any subsequence of $x_n$ converges to $x$. Let's show the converse.

Suppose ad absurdum, that every subsequence $x_{n_k}$ of $x_n$ has a subsequence $x_{n_{k_i}}$ converging to the same limit $x$, but $x_n$ does not converges to $x$. Then, we can extract a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ of $x_n$ such that $d(x,x_{n_k})>\epsilon$, for some $\epsilon>0$. On the other hand, by hypothesis we know that there is a convergent subsequence $x_{n_{k_i}}$ of $x_{n_k}$ that converges to $x$, but this is a contradiction, because $d(x,x_{n_{k_i}})>\epsilon$ and hence, $x_n\rightarrow x$.

Comment: +1 I''ll just add a clarification for readers: the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem (every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence) does not hold in $C^k$, since closed bounded sets are not necessarily compact in this function space. But the statement in the OP, which is not the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, holds in every metric space.

Comment: I was trying to write something exaplaining it, but my english is so bad that I give up. Anyway, now I feel more confortable with my answer. Thanks Pavel.

Comment: @Tomás Thank you for your answer! Your proof is what I need! :)

Comment: @5pm: Your answers and comments always help me to deepen the understanding of the questions I posted, thank you very much!

Comment: @5pm: By the way, what's the meaning of the abbreviation "OP" in your comment above?

Comment: @Darryl Original Post. Also used to mean Original Poster.